# Running Stick Figure in Sprite Kit Animation

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit

I am playing around a little bit in SpriteKit, and am trying to make a stick figure run. Due to my lack of experience, I believe I have started this process in an unconventional way.

Instead of drawing out each individual motion frame, I loaded the Separate images of the stick figure (ie the Head, the knee, the Thigh, the body, the arm, etc.) and told them to move accordingly. So far, everything fits together except for the motion and rotation of knee during the running sequence.

My problem is this:

When the thigh pulls back in it's stride, the knee becomes detached, and follows a straight line to the end of the stride while rotating.

My Question is this:

Is there a way to connect the thigh node to the calf node, as if it they were attached at a "knee" per say, while in motion? or is there some more efficient way?

Here is a snippet of my code, It may be a little more descriptive than I have been.

```
   func thigh_run(){
        //running config
        //DONT CHANGE!
        var thigh_rotation = CGFloat(M_PI)*0.8
        //Can Change :)
        var run_speed = NSTimeInterval(0.25)

        // reset the action sequence... basically
        let pos_nuetralize = SKAction.rotateByAngle(thigh_rotation/2, duration: run_speed)
        let neg_nuetralize = SKAction.rotateByAngle(-thigh_rotation/2, duration: run_speed)            
        //strides
        let thigh_pull = SKAction.rotateByAngle(-thigh_rotation, duration: run_speed*2)
        let thigh_stride = SKAction.rotateByAngle(thigh_rotation/2, duration: run_speed)           
        // for the opposite leg
        let b_thigh_pull = SKAction.rotateByAngle(-thigh_rotation/2, duration: run_speed)
        let b_thigh_stride = SKAction.rotateByAngle(thigh_rotation, duration: run_speed*2)

        //knee movement       
        let stride = SKAction.sequence([thigh_stride, thigh_pull, pos_nuetralize])
        let pull = SKAction.sequence([b_thigh_pull, b_thigh_stride, neg_nuetralize])
        r_arm.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(stride))
        f_leg_thigh.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(stride))
        b_leg_thigh.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(pull))
        //knee_run(run_speed)


    }

    func knee_run(speed: NSTimeInterval){

        let knee_stride = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(f_leg_thigh.position.x+f_leg_thigh.size.height, f_leg_thigh.position.y), duration: speed)
        let knee_reset = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(f_leg_thigh.position.x, f_leg_thigh.position.y-f_leg_thigh.size.height), duration: speed)
        let knee_pull_rotate = SKAction.rotateToAngle(CGFloat(M_PI)/2, duration: speed, shortestUnitArc: true)
        let knee_pull_rotate_half = SKAction.rotateToAngle(CGFloat(M_PI)*2, duration: speed, shortestUnitArc: true)
        let knee_pull_half = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(f_leg_thigh.position.x-f_leg_thigh.size.height, f_leg_thigh.position.y/2), duration: speed)
        let knee_pull = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(f_leg_thigh.position.x-f_leg_thigh.size.height, f_leg_thigh.position.y), duration: speed)




        //Grouping of the knee moving and rotating at the same time
        let knee_pull_group_half = SKAction.group([knee_pull_half, knee_pull_rotate_half])
        let knee_pull_group = SKAction.group([knee_pull, knee_pull_rotate])

        let f_knee_stride_seq = SKAction.sequence([knee_stride,knee_reset,knee_pull,knee_reset])
        let f_knee_pull_seq = SKAction.sequence([knee_pull_group_half, knee_reset, knee_stride, knee_reset])


        f_leg_calf.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(f_knee_stride_seq))
        b_leg_calf.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(f_knee_pull_seq))          
    }
```

I understand it may be hard to read, I have Documented it for myself pretty well. the f_ prefix is for "front"*leg and b* is for "back"_leg. think of it as right leg and left leg however.

Anyway! Thanks in advance! I appreciate any help or tips! Comment for any further explanation! :)

Comment: Could you post a gif of the animation achieved?

Answer (score 2):

The more efficient way is to use SKPhysicsJoint to connect the thigh node to the calf node.

Comment: would the motion of the thigh node alone also move the calf node?

Comment: @luckybroman5 - It will. The kind of motion depends on the kind of joint you use. Google "SKPhysicsJoint Tutorial" and you get a couple of good hits. Not sure about SWIFT versions yet.